# How to swap palettes in PNG images with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, png, image-manipulation

I need to alter the palette data in PNG images using JavaScript. I would like to do this without using WebGL and drawing to canvass, since this can be... inefficient, and cause slowdown. However, I'm not experienced with working with data compression and I know PNGs use compression.

I have three questions. One, do I need to fully decompress the image, or is it possible to only decompress parts up to the PLTE chunk(s) then re-compress the image?

Two, can JavaScript even work with raw binary data, or will I need to get really creative with base64 and string manipulation?

Third, since I'm working with palette and not truecolor images and so don't need to handle IDAT chunks... are the previous chunks actually compressed? Is this going to even require me to decompress the image?

Comment: Read the [PNG Specifications](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Contents.html), as it will answer your questions on the chunks and their compression. (The answer to #3 is "you don't need to know" and "no".)

Comment: .. the answer to #1 is "not at all", and #2: oh absolutely. It actually depends on your JS version, but even "being creative with strings" is perfectly doable with pure binary data. Check out my own [pnglib.jsx](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/783358) -- it's made to run inside InDesign, but I guess the basics of manipulating PNG chunks are compatible with other JS dialects.

Comment: Thank you, that actually does help between the specifications and the coding example. I've always learned best by examples and figuring out how the code works.